# converting between costmap_2d::Costmap2D and nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid

Tags: ros, navigation, occupancy-grid, 2dcostmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there an established or convenient way to convert between these two? I don't see any methods that suggest this is possible.

The manual approach of course is to create a message and populate it by iterating over all the cells in  the Costmap2D, but this seems like something that might already exist.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236841/converting-between-costmap_2d::costmap2d-and-nav_msgs::occupancygrid/) by [petermitrano](https://answers.ros.org/users/21252/petermitrano/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2016-06-13

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That functionality seems to be part of [costmap_2d_publisher](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/jade-devel/costmap_2d/src/costmap_2d_publisher.cpp) See `Costmap2DPublisher::prepareGrid()`

But I don't know of a more general-purpose function either.

---

Originally posted by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) with karma: 1788 on 2016-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [petermitrano](https://answers.ros.org/users/21252/petermitrano/) on 2016-06-14**:
+1 for finding the function that does it. This seems like something that should be added as a method to Costmap2D